# Set as 'disabled' the empty_value option in a formBuilder in Symfony 2.4

Tags: symfony

I'm using the option empty_value of a choice field in a form builder, and I'd like to set it as 'disabled' in the generated HTML for avoiding the user to select that option.
There is an option called 'disabled' in the field type, but I don't know how to implement it in empty_value, if it's possible.

This is the important part of the builder. It works, but the empty option can be selected.

```
->add('game', 'entity', array(
    'empty_data'  => null,
    'empty_value' => 'Selecciona un juego',
    'class'=>'GameBundle:Game',
    'property'=>'name',
    'multiple'=>false
    ))
```

Docs about it:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new form theme which renders the default choice as disabled. All you have to do is override the `choice_widget_collapsed` collapsed block as such:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required and empty_value is none and not empty_value_in_choices %}
        {% set required = false %}
    {% endif %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if empty_value is not none %}
            <option value=""{% if required %} disabled="disabled"{% if value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}{% endif %}>{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
    </select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```

**Important Note:** This was the original behavior of the `choice` form type. However, this was removed due to a problem with BB10 browsers. See commit [97cbb19b](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/97cbb19bcef308c384b308ba93a72d9a5d2cb75e).